# working with fifo data on linux using dotnet core

Tags: c#, linux, .net-core, pipe

I would like to use Linux's fifo-like stream on disk (created by using mkfifo) with C# code (dotnet core). I am looking for examples with using data on disk but I have trouble with finding ones.

I would like to make some modifications of fifo data on disk (e.g. first.raw) and using another tool/task (written in dotnet core) read that fifo and make an another modification and send it to another fifo data (e.g. second.raw) and finally by using third tool/task read that second.raw data modify it and send to another fifo data (e.g. third.raw) to read it by another tool.

Is it possible using dotnet core on Linux? Is there any correct way to do that on Linux (queue, named pipes)?

**EDIT**
When I am doing this on Ubuntu 18.04 (before running: mkfifo fifoStream.pipe):

```
FileStream fs = File.OpenWrite( "fifoStream.pipe" );  
using (var sw = new StreamWriter(fs))  
{  
  sw.WriteLine("first line");  
  sw.Flush();
}    
fs.Close();
```

and running code it hang up and I have to use ctrl+c to stop execution of the app.

Comment: Please show us what you have tried

Comment: On Linux or UNIX (nearly) everything is a file, so you can open a FIFO like any other file. The `open` will block until the other end opens it as well, and `read` or `write` operations may block if the FIFO buffer is empty or full respectively. You cannot modify FIFO data **on disk**, you can only read data from a FIFO, modify it and write it to somewhere else, e.g. to another FIFO. A FIFO created by `mkfifo` **is** a named pipe.

Comment: A pipe is standard input/output.  In c# Standard Input/Output is Console.Read() and Console.Write().

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution for Ubuntu 18.04. 
As per: https://johnkoerner.com/csharp/IPC-in-net-core-using-protobuf/
This works for my case:

first running "server" code:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Starting Server");

    var pipe = new NamedPipeServerStream("fifoStream.pipe", PipeDirection.InOut);
    Console.WriteLine("Waiting for connection....");
    pipe.WaitForConnection();

    Console.WriteLine("Connected");
    pipe.WriteByte(66);
    pipe.Disconnect();
}
```

then running "client" code:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Starting Client");
    var pipe = new NamedPipeClientStream(".", "fifoStream.pipe", PipeDirection.InOut, PipeOptions.None);
    Console.WriteLine("Connecting");
    pipe.Connect();
    pipe.ReadByte(); //here I receive byte 66

    Console.WriteLine("Done");
}
```